# Inconsistency Errors in kombu using celery and redis with the key '_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox'

Tags: python-3.x, django, redis, celery, kombu

I have two Django sites (archive and test-archive) on one machine. Each has its own virtual environment and different celery queues and daemons, using Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04, Django 3.0.2, Redis v 4.0.9, celery v 4.3, and Kombu v4.6.3. This server has 16 GB of RAM, and under load there is at least 10GB free and swap is minimal.

I keep getting this error in my logs:

```
kombu.exceptions.InconsistencyError: 
Cannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists.
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.
```

I tried

- downgrading Kombu to 4.5 for both sites per some stackoverflow posts
- and setting `maxmemory=2GB` and `maxmemory-policy=allkeys-lru` in `redis.conf` per celery docs (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html#broker-redis); originally the settings were the defaults of `unlimited` memory and `noeviction` and these errors were present for both versions of kombu

I still get those errors when one site is under load (i.e. doing something like uploading a set of images and processing them) and the other site is idle.

What is a little strange is that on some test runs using test-archive, test-archive will not have any errors, while archive will show those errors, even though the archive site is not doing anything. On other identical test runs using test-archive, test-archive will generate the errors and archive will not.

I know this is a reported bug in kombu/celery, so I am wondering if anyone has a work around that works more often than not for this configuration. What versions of celery, kombu, redis, etc. seem to work more often than not? I am happy to share my config files or log files, but there are so many I thought it would be best to start this discussion with the problem statement and my setup and see what else is needed.

Thanks!